# aiorgam python обработка сообщений от пользователя

Tags: python, telegram-bot, requests, telebot, aiogram

Для начала. Многие, кто работают с aiogram, знают о конструкции:

```
class name_class(StatesGroup):
    mess = State()
```

Он хранит сообщение пользователя (**но обрабатывает только текст введенный пользователем**). Но проблема и вопрос в чем. Вопрос в том как с помощью **aiogram** можно **принимать сообщения от пользователей** с **файлами, прицепленной музыкой** или еще чем-то. **Все, что мне нужно будет взять из такого рода сообщения - это message.chat.id и message.message_id**.

Если в aiogram нету такого способа обработки сообщений, то можно объяснить как это сделать через прямые запросы (**telegram bot api + request**).

**Заранее всем спасибо!!!**

**:Правка + пример кода:**

```
class accept_new_massage(StatesGroup):
    mess = State()
    shortD = State()


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="save_new_massage")
async def Save_new_massage(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(query.id)
    await accept_new_massage.mess.set()
    await query.message.answer("Введите ваше сообщение: ")

@dp.message_handler(state=accept_new_massage.mess)
async def Аccept_new_massage(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
   global temporaryMemory

    temporaryMemory.append({
        "userID": message.chat.id,
        "typeActions": "saveMes",
        "data":{
            "IDMessage": message.message_id,
            "shortDescription": None,
            "levelOfBeingChosen": 0,
            "listOfHashtags": None
        }
    })
```

Вообщем... Когда я отправляю телеграм боту сообщение имеющее не только text, но еще и какой то фаил или фото или музыку, то **accept_new_massage не принимает это за сообщение** и **не запускает функцию Аccept_new_massage** по хендлеру введенного пользователем сообщению. Если стало более понятно То это хорошо.

Comment: Если в кратце как это должно работать.

Бот отправляет запрос на воод сообщения п типу message.answer("Введите ваше сообщение: ")
В этот момент **бот должен ожидать ввод от пользователя** (сообщение **внутри могут быть файлы и текст вообще любого содержания**). Сам бот когда получает сообщение должен взять message.chat.id и message.message_id (то есть id чата и id сообщеня в этом чате). Больше от бота ничего не требуется.
**Еще раз спасибо!!!**

Comment: А кто Вам сказал, что это работает только с текстами?

Comment: потому что он не реагирует на введенное пользователем сообщение с файлом или простым фото (обновил трейд там прописал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делай вот так

```
@dp.message_handler(state=accept_new_massage.mess, content_types=types.ContentTypes.ANY)
```

Теперь он должен ловить всё.

Comment: я только сам до этого дошел((((
ну чего ты так поздно появился дорогой мой:D

Comment: Ну как только увидел вопрос сразу и ответил :)

Answer (score 0):

Кароче... покапался немного в message_handler и content_types... немного разобрался что типы сообщений бывают разные и чтобы выбрать вообще все сообщения можно приминить примерно такой хэндлер

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=[types.ContentType.ANY], state=accept_new_massage.mess)
```

он благополучно обрабатывает все сообщения и реагирует на них... правда скажу нигде этого не находил просто случайно натыкал)